# c# looping only prints first loop

Tags: c#, printing

I have a function which reads a whole file and then a separate function which prints out the contents to a text document but it only prints at the first loop.

my code is:

```
private void LineModule ( StreamReader reader,StreamWriter writer1 = null)      //Interpretes line objects in the DXF file
{
    // creates a StreamWriter ready to write data to a file
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("blahblah.txt"))
    {
        string line1, line2;
        line1 = "0";
        line2 = "0";          
        double x1= 0;
        double y1 = 0;
        double x2= 0;
        double y2 = 0;

        do
        {
            GetLineCouple(reader, out line1, out line2);

            if (line2 != "EOF")
            { }
            if (line1 == "10")
            {
                x1 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);

                if (x1 > XMax)
                    XMax = x1;

                if (x1 < XMin)
                    XMin = x1;
            }

            if (line1 == "20")
            {
                y1 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);

                if (y1 > YMax)
                    YMax = y1;

                if (y1 < YMin)
                    YMin = y1;
                string xyz1 = (x1 + "," + line2 + ",0.0");
                xyz1 = xyz1.TrimEnd();
                writer.WriteLine(xyz1);
            }

            if (line1 == "11")
            {
                x2 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);

                if (x2 > XMax)
                    XMax = x2;

                if (x2 < XMin)
                    XMin = x2;
            }

            if (line1 == "21")
            {
                y2 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);

                if (y2 > YMax)
                    YMax = y2;

                if (y2 < YMin)
                    YMin = y2;
                string xyz2 = (x2 + "," + line2 + ",0.0\n");
                xyz2 = xyz2.TrimEnd();
                writer.WriteLine(xyz2);
            }
        }
        while (line1 != "21");
```

The first loop is exactly what I want but I want it to print out all the loops to file.

And the getlinecouple function:

```
private void GetLineCouple(StreamReader theReader, out string line1, out string line2, StreamWriter writer1 = null)     //this method is used to iterate through the text file and assign values to line1 and line2
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    string decimalSeparator = ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;

    {
        line1 = line2 = "";
        if (theReader == null)
            return;

        line1 = theReader.ReadLine();
        if (line1 != null)
        {
            line1 = line1.Trim();
            line1 = line1.Replace('.', decimalSeparator[0]);
            // writer1.WriteLine(line1);
        }
        line2 = theReader.ReadLine();

        if (line2 != null)
        {
            line2 = line2.Trim();
            line2 = line2.Replace('.', decimalSeparator[0]);
            //writer1.WriteLine(line2);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the value of line1 in the first loop?

Comment: Please put a bit more effort into formatting your code in future - the indentation is hit and miss here; also, use spaces instead of tabs. Always use the preview to check that the code looks like you want it to look before posting.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in you code.  Making my head hurt trying to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the value of `line1` "21" after the first pass through the loop?

You should run debugger and step through the code. That way you can see the variable values at each step and can check your exit condition.

I've refactored your LineModule method to extract some repeated code and fix some issues:

```
private void LineModule ( StreamReader reader,StreamWriter writer1 = null)     //Interpretes line objects in the DXF file
{
    // creates a StreamWriter ready to write data to a file
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("blahblah.txt"))
    {

        string line1 = "0", line2 = "0";
        double x1= 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;

        do
        {
            GetLineCouple(reader, out line1, out line2);

            switch (line1)
            {
                case "10":
                    x1 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);
                    SetMaxMin(x1, ref XMax, ref XMin);
                    break;
                case "20":
                    y1 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);
                    SetMaxMin(y1, ref YMax, ref YMin);
                    PrintXYX(x1, line2, writer);
                    break;
                case "11":
                    x2 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);
                    SetMaxMin(x2, ref XMax, ref XMin);
                    break;
                case "21":
                    y2 = Convert.ToDouble(line2);
                    SetMaxMin(y2, ref YMax, ref YMin);
                    PrintXYZ(x2, line2, writer);
                    break;
                default:
                    // deal with other values here
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (line1 != "21");
    }
}

private static void PrintXYZ(double value, string lineValue, StreamWriter writer)
{
    string xyz = (value + "," + lineValue + ",0.0");
    writer.WriteLine(xyz);
}

private static void SetMaxMin(double value, ref double max, ref double min)
{
    if (value > max)
    {
        max = value
    }

    if (value < min)
    {
        min = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug GetLineCouple, and watch line1 value. I guess it is set to 21 in during the first iteration. And when it goes to line != 21 it returns false and it exits the while loop.

Comment: Actually I'm not right, can you please post the code of GetLineCouple method.

Comment: But then it would just run continuously.

Comment: I have edited the question and put the getLinecouple function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers.

I figured it out by changing the while != "21" to while != "EOF" and then it loops through the whole file.

the only issue now is that the program crashes but it does output the correct information.

Thank you again